# Why does it throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a frame that has a table and an exit button.  I want to add some data to my table, but this doesn't work correctly:  when I open my frame at first, the data is OK, e.g., "Nima,Rahmani,...", then I click the exit button and open my frame again, the table now has "Nima,Rahmani,..." two times, and when I click exit button now, an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown.

My frame:

```
public class DeathList extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private Admin admin;
private ArrayList<Death> list;
DefaultTableModel model;

/** Creates new form DeathList */
public DeathList(Admin admin) {
    initComponents();
    this.admin = admin;
    Manager.admin = admin;
    try {
        Manager.addToDeathListFromMySQL();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DeathList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    fillTable();

}

private void fillTable() {
    String[] columNames = {"name", "family", "father's name", "date of birth",
                           "date of death", "date of confirmation",
                           "grave column", "grave row"};
    List<Death> death = admin.getDeathList();
    if (death.isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Death list is empty! First, add a person.",
                                      "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } else {

        Object[][] data = new Object[death.size()][columNames.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            Death death1 = death.get(i);
            data[i][0] = death1.getName();
            data[i][1] = death1.getFamily();
            data[i][2] = death1.getFatherName();
            data[i][3] = death1.getDateOfBirth();
            data[i][4] = death1.getDateOfDeath();
            data[i][5] = death1.getDateOfConfirmation();
            data[i][6] = death1.getGraveColumn();
            data[i][7] = death1.getGraveRow();

        }
        model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columNames);
        jTable1.setModel(model);

    }

}
private void cBActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    List<String> d = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> d1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> d2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> d3 = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < jTable1.getRowCount(); i++) {
        String name = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(i, 0);
        String name1 = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(i, 1);
        String name2 = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(i, 2);
        String name3 = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(i, 3);
        if (name != null && name1 != null && name2 != null && name3 != null) {
            d.add(name);
            d1.add(name1);
            d2.add(name2);
            d3.add(name3);
            d.clear();
            d1.clear();
            d2.clear();
            d3.clear();
            Object[][] data1 = new Object[i][4];
            for (int j = 0; j < data1.length; j++) {
                String s = d.get(j);
                String s1 = d1.get(j);
                String s2 = d2.get(j);
                String s3 = d3.get(j);
                data1[j][0] = s;
                data1[j][1] = s1;
                data1[j][2] = s2;
                data1[j][3] = s3;
            }

            model = new DefaultTableModel(data1, 4);
            jTable1.setModel(model);
            fillTable();

        } else {
            fillTable();
        }
    }
    int r = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Are you sure?", "Message",
                                          JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
    if (r == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        this.dispose();// TODO add your handling code here:
    }
}}
```

stackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
    at AdminGUI.DeathList.cBActionPerformed(DeathList.java:192)
    at AdminGUI.DeathList.access$000(DeathList.java:28)
    at AdminGUI.DeathList$1.actionPerformed(DeathList.java:122)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3265)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
        at AdminGUI.DeathList.cBActionPerformed(DeathList.java:192)
        at AdminGUI.DeathList.access$000(DeathList.java:28)
        at AdminGUI.DeathList$1.actionPerformed(DeathList.java:122)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
        at

javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3265)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
```

Comment: Relatively simple solution, but since you've only accepted 1 answer out of the last 15 questions you have asked I don't see the point in answering the question. Either you don't read the answers or you don't appreciate the help you receive

Comment: Whats wrong in using a decent Debugger here? This is probably a good lesson to learn to find out by yourself. In Eclipse for instance you are able to add certain Exceptions to be recognized (Breakpoint View -> "Add Java Exception breakpoin") and let the debugger stop whenever they *will* occurr. Means: You let your program run and it stops at the location where the exception (IndexOutOfBoundsException here) occurrs. Then you'll use the Variable View and check whats happening.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is because you add something in a list

```
d.add(name);
```

you clear the list,

```
d.clear();
```

then you try to access the element from that list:

```
String s = d.get(j); // IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Comment: Did you read my comment? People won't change if you continue to spoon feeed them answers. All the questions posted by this individual are basic homework questions and the individual has not listened to suggestions on simple ways to debug code or on following up with a simple "thank you", which is done by accepting the proper answer. Only when people stop providing answers will the behaviour change because then the individual will start failing the course.

Comment: @camickr rather apt that I stumbled across this question nearly 3 years later and this answer, correct and the only one that was posted, is still not accepted..